# Matlab's VideoReader not working on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: matlab, gstreamer, avi, ubuntu-17.04

I have been struggling to get VideoReader working on Ubuntu 17.04.  If I run a simple program:

```
v = VideoReader('flame.avi')
```

I get the following:

```
Error using VideoReader/init (line 619)

Could not read file due to an unexpected error. Reason: Unable to initialize the video obtain properties

Error in VideoReader (line 172)
        obj.init(fileName);
```

Now, I have done a little bit of digging, and most people say that this error comes from not having gstreamer0.10 installed.

See: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/165584-cannot-read-video-matlab-2014b-linux

This one says that gstreamer1.0 is not sufficient to fix this problem: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/255157-can-t-load-video-using-videoreader-in-matlab-r2015-on-ubuntu-15-04-could-not-read-file-due-to-an-un

The problem comes from trying to install gstreamer0.10.  It doesn't appear to be working in Ubuntu 17.

This one talks about how gstreamer isn't working on Ubuntu 17: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/294258-hello-i-have-a-problem-with-videoreader-on-matlab-r2016a-with-ubtuntu-lts16-04

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to overcome this issue?  Is there a different package that I could install that would fulfill the same requirements?  I have tried installing matlab-support, and that hasn't helped either.  Is there a different issue other than gstreamer0.10?

I would prefer not to re-install Ubuntu 16.04, but understand if that is the only way.  But surely, someone has gotten MATLAB working on Ubuntu 17?

Answer (score 4):

A colleague of mine found a link to a post that solved my problem https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/329796-issue-with-libstdc-so-6

Essentially, you need to redirect MATLAB and tell it to not use its default libstdc++6 file and use your Linux system's instead.  I went with the solution at the bottom, and wrote an alias for my .bashrc file.

```
alias matlab='LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.22 /usr/local/bin/matlab -desktop'
```

After testing it out, I have confirmed it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and I was able to solve it by running

`sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-plugins-*`

on Ubuntu 20.04 with MATLAB R2018a

Moreover, forcing MATLAB to use the system libstdc++ in ways 1. and 2. did not solve the problem:

1. Write in `~/.bashrc`
   `alias matlab='LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.22 /usr/local/bin/matlab -desktop'`
   closing the terminal, open again, run matlab and still did not work.
2. going to  `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/sys/os/glnxa64` and adding .bak to all libstdc++ files (as a means of making them "invisible" to matlab and force it to look for them in the system) did not work either.

**EDIT**
This is working for at least one video, but still other videos give me the same error. So it is not a full solution

**EDIT**

One such video I could not open with matlab's video reader becomes accessible after converting it with this script (using opencv).

```
import cv2
import tqdm

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("output.avi")

vw = None
nframes = 100
# for fast test, change the for loop to
# while True:
# to convert the whole video

for _ in tqdm.tqdm(range(nframes)):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break
    if vw is None:
        vw = cv2.VideoWriter("output_safe.avi", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'), 10, (frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]))
    vw.write(frame)


cap.release()
if vw is None:
    vw.release()
```

These were the properties of the original video as reported with `ffmpeg -i output.avi`

```
Input #0, avi, from 'output.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.64.100
  Duration: 00:01:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1822 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (FMP4 / 0x34504D46), yuv420p, 2592x1944 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 1817 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
```

and these are the new properties

```
Input #0, avi, from 'output_safe.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.61.100
  Duration: 00:00:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7594 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline) (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 2592x1944, 7650 kb/s, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 10 tbn, 10 tbc
```