# Unable to initialize the video obtain properties. Matlab2017b, Ubuntu20.04 LTS

Tags: matlab, ubuntu

When I read a `.avi` video in Matlab using `VideoReader`, I also encountered this problem in `VideoReader/init` function: `Unable to initialize the video obtain properties`.

My platform is matlab2017b, ubuntu20.04LTS. To tackle this problem, I did these steps.

First, I changed my gstreamer version from 1.0 to 0.10, by using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-tools 
gstreamer0.10-plugins-good
```

I also downloaded `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg` at [http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg/gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg_0.10.13-5ubuntu1~vivid_amd64.deb](http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg/gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg_0.10.13-5ubuntu1%7Evivid_amd64.deb), then used `dpkg -i` to install.

I used `dpkg -L` to check if these packages were successfully installed. No problem.

However, the problem was still exist after I rebooted system.

Second, I tried this solution [Matlab's VideoReader not working on Ubuntu 17.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48325217/matlabs-videoreader-not-working-on-ubuntu-17-04).
By replacing the soft link of `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2017b/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6` to the system `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28`.

It also did not work. I feel strange about this problem that, it is caused by the system compatibility? Are there an effective solution? Or, How should I analyze this problem?

Note:

1. I tested some `.avi` videos originated from https://github.com/andrewssobral/lrslibrary/tree/master/dataset, in which only `demo.avi` was readed successfully.
2. I also tested some customed `.avi` videos generated using `Opencv VideoWriter` with `fourcc=XVID and PIM1`, all of them were failured.

Answer (score 0):

I tried these solutions on matlab2017b, it did not work. The only reason I considered is compatibility of the system.
Finally, I replaced matlab's version from 2017b to 2016b, which solved the problem described.
For matlab2016b, I only did the first step by replacing gstreamer from 1.0 to 0.10, and installing gstreamder0.10-ffmpeg.